# What is the difference between ZonedDateTime.withZoneSameInstant and ZonedDateTime.withZoneSameLocal?

Tags: java, java-time

Let's say I have a ZonedDateTime:

```
ZonedDateTime zonedDateTime = 
     ZonedDateTime.of(LocalDateTime.now(), ZoneId.of("US/Pacific"));
```

I would like to know which date/time it is let's say in Berlin.
I have two methods :

```
zonedDateTime.withZoneSameInstant(ZoneId.of("Europe/Berlin")); // probably this is the right one to get the corresponding date/time in Berlin

zonedDateTime.withZoneSameLocal(ZoneId.of("Europe/Berlin"));
```

The docs for the `withZoneSameLocal` method say: "The local date-time is only changed if it is invalid for the new zone..." and it's not clear when this really can happen (any example ? =)).

**Which date/time each of them represents and what is the difference?**

Answer (score 25, accepted):

If you want to convert a timestamp from one timezone to another, use `withZoneSameInstant()`. `withZoneSameLocal()` will change the zone but keep all the other fields the same. The exception is where it would be an invalid date in that timezone.

For example,

```
ZonedDateTime dtUTC = ZonedDateTime.parse("2019-03-10T02:30:00Z");
ZoneId pacific = ZoneId.of("US/Pacific");
System.out.println(dtUTC.withZoneSameInstant(pacific));
System.out.println(dtUTC.withZoneSameLocal(pacific));
```

[prints](https://ideone.com/iUnxwK)

```
2019-03-09T18:30-08:00[US/Pacific]
2019-03-10T03:30-07:00[US/Pacific]
```

The first line is the original timestamp converted to another timezone. The second *tries* to preserve the date/time fields, but 2:30 is not a valid time on that date (because of the Daylight Savings jump), so it shifts it by an hour.

Comment: so does it mean that withZoneSameInstant don't handle the Daylight savings where withZoneSameInstant takes care of it? @shmosel

Comment: They're both DST-aware.