# ElasticSearch Term Aggregation script timezone conversion

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-painless

I'm really struggling with this. In Painless, how would I update the following:

```
 "aggs": {
    "total_messages_per_day_of_week": {
      "terms": {
        "script": {
          "lang": "painless",
          "source": "doc['date'].value.dayOfWeek"
        }
      },
```

To convert the UTC datetime in doc.date to a locale (e.g. 'America/Los_Angeles') BEFORE getting the day of week?

Basically I want to aggregate by day number, but where day number represents the desired timezone day, not UTC day.

Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You'd do it like this by first transforming your UTC date into a `ZonedDateTime` via `Instant.atZone()` and then taking the day of the week:

```
Instant date = Instant.ofEpochMilli(doc['timestamp'].value);
ZonedDateTime zdt = date.atZone(ZoneId.of('America/Los_Angeles'));
return zdt.getDayOfWeek().getValue();
```

And since `doc.date.value` is actually [`JodaCompatibleZonedDateTime`](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/blob/master/server/src/main/java/org/elasticsearch/script/JodaCompatibleZonedDateTime.java) (i.e. a delegate of `ZonedDateTime`), in your aggregation you can try this:

```
{
  ...,
  "aggs": {
    "days": {
      "terms": {
        "script": "doc['timestamp'].value. withZoneSameInstant(ZoneId.of('America/Los_Angeles')).getDayOfWeek().getValue()"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, just tried this with:

"aggs":{
      "period":{
         "terms":{
            "script":{
               "source":"Instant.ofEpochMilli(doc['timestamp'].value).atZone(ZoneId.of('America/Los_Angeles')).getDayOfWeek().getValue()",
               "lang":"painless"
            }
         },

'timestamp' is the actual field, not date.

I get the following error:

wrong_method_type_exception: cannot convert MethodHandle(Dates)JodaCompatibleZonedDateTime to (Object)long

Comment: What do you mean by `'timestamp' is the actual field, not date`?

Comment: I mean the name of the property that stores the date in the doc is 'timestamp'. I used 'date' above to add clarity. Wanted to ensure that the error made sense to you. Thanks

Comment: Ok, makes sense. See my updated answer, it should work

Comment: That is brilliant. Thank you for your help. Very much appreciated.

Comment: Yes, my thoughts exactly. Thank you.

Comment: Slight amendment - I needed to use withZoneSameInstant rather than withZoneSameLocal. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55032725/what-is-the-difference-between-zoneddatetime-withzonesameinstant-and-zoneddateti

Comment: Very good point I've overlooked! I've fixed the issue! Thanks for reporting this 